Post apocalyptic film, with odd cars, US and UK actors iirc
I wish to ask about a post apocalyptic film, with odd cars and UK and US actors (as far as I recall) screened in the 80s and 90s. My recollection would suggest it was made any time between 1968-1982, but I would think the early 70s is the more likely time in which it was filmed.
Key details:

Some of the action took place in areas of quite lush vegetation, as opposed to the scorched earth / desert type landscapes seen in other post apocalyptic films.
I recall at least one car being a 60s or 70s American estate or large saloon which had exhaust pipes routed around the outside of the car, up to roof level.
The actors, scenes and sets that I can recall in my mind remind me of US Star Trek programmes of the 60s, and the English UFO TV series, however I have not been able to ascertain any connection to the makers of those two programmes. I have a feeling it might have included an actor or two who had played a minor part in Star Trek, however the passage of time since I saw it means I cannot swear to that.
The film was a drama, felt a bit like a TV movie or pilot, but had elements of humour too. The society which had developed had very virile men, or at least one man claimed that - a line that sticks in my mind "Our men fathered as many as 38 children, I fathered only 21", and I remember a blonde lady, an English actress (in her 40s I would think at the time of this film), who was very impressed by this.
That's all I can recall really, and I have asked and searched around a lot for this, to no avail yet.


Were they exhaust pipes? Your description made me think of a movie or TV show in which "old" cars were adapted to run on wood gas or something; they had "cookers" in the back with large pipes feeding forward to the engine. I can't recall anything about the show other than the old converted cars; maybe we are thinking of the same show.

You may be thinking of one of two films: "Genesis II", and "Planet Earth"
Both were made for television (1973 and 1974) by Gene Roddenberry as pilots for TV series, neither of which was produced. Both stories follow a scientist who reaches the apocalyptic future via suspended animation, as in  the Buck Rogers serial. "Planet Earth" had a scene with militaristic mutants driving makeshift tanks created from pre-apocalypse cars, and also a more advanced matriarchal culture in opposition to the mutants.
When I watched these films back in the 1970s, I thought that "Planet Earth" was a sequel to "Genesis II", but I've since learned that the second pilot movie was a remake of the first, apparently an attempt to re-pilot the same series.
Below is a link to an article about these films, and some of Gene Roddenberry's other pilot attempts.
https://www.cancelledscifi.com/2023/11/18/cancelled-before-they-began-the-lost-gene-roddenberry-shows-of-the-60s-and-70s/

Multiple answers should be posted as multiple answers, not multiple choices within a single answer

I believe the movie the OP is looking for is Planet Earth. It has the breeding discussion, and does show modified old cars with rerouted exhaust. 1 minute YouTube clip. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmmTqfVLw6c

The blond is probably Diana Muldaur. But while she is not English, she does have an English bearing.

@Valorum The linked article makes clear that both movies were really pilots for the same show, so I think it makes sense to include them as one answer, although the answer itself could be clearer on that point.
